# Why is the production of aramid fibers expensive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

When comparing knitted fibers for the production of clothing, aramid based fibers trade at many times the price of classics synthetic fibers per $\mathrm{m}^2$.

Despite the limited supply of aramid fibers, what are the core drivers in production costs when compared to classical synthetic fibers?